# including several lattice graphs with grid

Tags: r, lattice

I wonder if anyone can point me the way to arrange several graphs created with lattice in a grid.

The example:

```
    library(lattice) 
attach(mtcars)

# create factors with value labels 
gear.f<-factor(gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
               labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears")) 
cyl.f <-factor(cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
               labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

# kernel density plot 
a<-densityplot(~mpg, 
            main="Density Plot", 
            xlab="Miles per Gallon")
```

Ok, so I have created the a plot.

After reading previous post, I have learn how to arrange this in a grid with grid.arranje

```
library(latticeExtra)

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(a,a, nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

I want to generate a graph with two plots in the first row, two plots in the second and three plots in the third and forth row.

I have tried the following, witch doesn´t work

```
grid.arrange(a,a,a,a,ncol=2,(arrangeGrob(a,a,a,a,a,a,ncol=2)))
```

Is it possible to do want I want, starting from my code?

Comment: see `?plot.trellis`, in particular the `split` and `more` arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With gridExtra,

```
library(gridExtra)
a <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="grey90"))
row12 <- arrangeGrob(a, a, a, a, ncol=2)
row34 <- arrangeGrob(a, a, a, a, a, a, ncol=3)
grid.arrange(row12, row34, ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: baptiste, that it, thanks a lot. The tip on ?plot.trellis was also helpfull.